# How can I perform Partial Fractions Decomposition on a Telescoping Series involving Exponentials?

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-fractions

Given:

$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty\dfrac{6^k}{(3^k - 2^k)(3^{k+1} - 2^{k+1})}$

The Partial Fractions Decomposition is:

$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty(\dfrac{3^k}{3^k - 2^k} - \dfrac{3^{k+1}}{3^{k+1} - 2^{k+1}})$

But I cannot derive the decomposition myself, no matter what I try. Could someone therefore provide the steps to calculate the decomposition along with their reasoning?

Comment: whatever do you mean? the answer is already given. You cannot verify?

Comment: I know the answer is given, but my issue is how do I calculate it. (i.e. say I hadn't posted the answer, how would I have gotten there?) (so yes, I cannot verify the answer)

Comment: In that case, you just have to try-and-error twice to get it.

Comment: If it helps, you can equivalently consider breaking into partial fractions $\dfrac{xy}{(x-y)(3x-2y)}$.

Comment: Macavity I up vote you in spirit, as I don't have the necessary points to do it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write
$$\begin{align*}6^k &= (6^k)(3-2) \\&= 3^{k+1}2^k - 3^k2^{k+1}\\
&= 3^{k+1}2^k - 3^k2^{k+1} + 3^{2k+1} - 3^{2k+1}\end{align*}$$

take (first and fourth) and (second and third) term and factorise

it will split into the req form